# Why does checking if temp table exists when "CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL" is set to ON doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;  

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##QueryResults;
```

Why is it that if i set set `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` to off as shown above and temp table `##QueryResults` exists, it is successfully dropped but if i set it to ON, then temp table is not dropped even when it exists?

Comment: How are you testing this? There might be something wrong with the way you test it.

Comment: @FelixPamittan i have a stored procedure in which i have a select query whose results are inserted into temp table ##QueryResults. I'm just trying to drop the temp table first before the select query that re-creates it is executed. SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is deprecated (not entirely sure that's the right word...). It will be automatically set to `ON` while setting it to `OFF` will result in an error in a future release of sql-server. Hence using it is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected on SQL Server 2014 SP1

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;  
CREATE TABLE ##QueryResults (foo int);

SELECT OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults');
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##QueryResults;
SELECT OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults');
GO

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;  
CREATE TABLE ##QueryResults (foo int);

SELECT OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults');
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##QueryResults;
SELECT OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##QueryResults');
```

gives

```
-----------
373576369


-----------
NULL


-----------
389576426


-----------
NULL
```